# How to redirect after login in iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am working on an app and would like to know how to automatically redirect someone to their profile page or a home page after they login into my app?

If relevant I am using the Parse UI to log in and sign up and coding in swift and using Xcode7

Any advice welcomed

Answer (score 0):

`PFLoginViewController` has a delegate with calls that you can use to indicate when a user has successfully logged in. I believe it gets called when a user signs up as well, but I could be mistaken.

You can use those calls to signal a successful login/signup and then redirect to the appropriate view controller from there. If you want any more advice, you will need to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to redirect your user to specific view controller if user already logged in ? You can use below code in your app delegate file.

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.currentUser() 
if currentUser != nil {
   // Your redirect code 
}
```

Comment: so this would go in the app delegate because I am redirecting them to another view controller? or is this just one method, I ask because I am new to swift and would like to learn. I have also tried self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboard", sender: self) would that be also a proper way?